# copy directories only cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to copy an unknown number of directories (including the files inside them)  from one location to another with a **batch file**.
My only problem is that I must not copy the files that are located in the same location as the directories.

For example:

Let say *c:\Folder\* contains the directories: *Dir1* and *Dir2* and the file: *f1*.

I want to copy *c:\Folder\Dir1* and *c:\Folder\Dir2* (and the files inside them) to *c:\Location* directory **but not** file: *f1*.

Help please!

Comment: check `xcopy` and `robocopy` commands .

Comment: Yeah... But they either copy the directories empty, or copy them properly but with file: f1 and as I sad I must void from coping it.

Comment: Do these files, which you won't copy like (f1), all on same direction and do they have the same file Extension?

Comment: They are all .xml files, f1 and the files inside Dir1 and Dir2, so I can't use the exclude option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set variable
set _SOURCE="C:\Temp\Test\"
set _DESTINATION="C:\Temp\New\"

REM Change Direction
pushd %_SOURCE%

FOR /D %%a in (*) DO xcopy /S /I %%a %_DESTINATION%%%a
```

- **/D** : Just directories
- **/S** : Copy subdirectories
- **/I** : Targets are directory (not file)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like...

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`DIR /AD /B C:\FOLDER`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\LOCATION\%%d" (MKDIR "C:\LOCATION\%%d")
    XCOPY /E "%%d" "C:\LOCATION\%%d"
)
```